# How to make chapter and section titles have title rules with different lengths?

Tags: titlesec, rules

First an MWE and its output are as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}%

\let\oldtitleline\titleline
\renewcommand{\titleline}{\oldtitleline*}
\setlength{\titlewidth}{0.3\textwidth}%
\newcommand{\periodafter}[1]{#1.}%

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{\wordsep}{\periodafter}[\addvspace{-0.1\baselineskip}{\hfill\titlerule[0.4pt]\hfill\null}]
\makeatother

\setlength{\titlewidth}{0.15\textwidth}%
\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{\thesection.}{\wordsep}{\periodafter}[\addvspace{-0.1\baselineskip}{\hfill\titlerule[0.4pt]\hfill\null}]
 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter title}
\section{A section title}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I reset the value of `\titlewidth` to change the length of title rule of section titles, but it doesn't work? So is there anyway to fix it, i.e., to make chapter and section title have title rules with different lengths?

Answer (score 2):

With your code, `\titleline` is *never* called.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\periodafter}[1]{#1.}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}
  {\wordsep}
  {\periodafter}
  [%
   \addvspace{-0.1\baselineskip}%
   \hspace*{\fill}\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hspace*{\fill}%
  ]

\titleformat{\section}
  {\filcenter}
  {\thesection.}
  {\wordsep}
  {\periodafter}
  [%
   \addvspace{-0.1\baselineskip}%
   \hspace*{\fill}\rule{0.15\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hspace*{\fill}%
  ]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter title}
\section{A section title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest a different definition of `\periodafter`, see the example why.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\periodafter}[1]{#1\@addpunct{.}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}
  {\wordsep}
  {\periodafter}
  [%
   \addvspace{-0.1\baselineskip}%
   \hspace*{\fill}\rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hspace*{\fill}%
  ]

\titleformat{\section}
  {\filcenter}
  {\thesection.}
  {\wordsep}
  {\periodafter}
  [%
   \addvspace{-0.1\baselineskip}%
   \hspace*{\fill}\rule{0.15\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hspace*{\fill}%
  ]
 
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter title}
\section{A section title!}

\end{document}
```

[image]